# Creating a sinusoidally colored pattern function in matlab

Tags: matlab

How do I create a sinusoidal colred image in matlab that has the same color in each column meaning one column has red next has green than blue than it repeats the same process again

Comment: Any specific details about the size of the image? Do you want a gradient from red to green then to blue or simply those pixels in that pattern?

Comment: size could be anything but the gradient needs to be in order red green and blue

Answer (score 0):

### No Gradient:

Sets every third column to red starting from 1. Sets every third column to green starting from 2. Sets every third column to blue starting from 3. Each column is set within the respective layer in the matrix corresponding to the correct colour channel. This indexing of columns is achieved by

```
Red_Channel = 1;
Image(:,1:3:Image_Width,Red_Channel) =  255;
```

Where, 
`:` indicates for all the rows

`1:3:Image_Width` indicates starting a column 1 and skipping by a factor 3 up to `Image_Width`.

`Red_Channel` is 1 and indicates the layer of the 3D matrix to set.

---

### RGB Conventions:

[image: RGB Conventions]

[image: RGB Conventions 2]
*Edit: Should be Image(:,:,2) for the green channel.*

[image: No Gradient]

### By Indexing the 3D Array/Matrix:

```
%Image size properties%
Image_Height = 50;
Image_Width = 50;
Number_Of_Colour_Channels = 3;
Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width,Number_Of_Colour_Channels);

Red_Channel = 1;
Green_Channel = 2;
Blue_Channel = 3;

%Setting every theird column starting at 1 to red%
Image(:,1:3:Image_Width,Red_Channel) =  255;
%Setting every theird column starting at 2 to green%
Image(:,2:3:Image_Width,Green_Channel) =  255;
%Setting every theird column starting at 3 to blue%
Image(:,3:3:Image_Width,Blue_Channel) =  255;

%Figure settings%
X_Position = 0;
Y_Position = 0;
Figure_Height = 300;
Figure_Width = 300;

imshow(Image,'InitialMagnification','fit');
set(gcf, 'Position',  [X_Position, Y_Position, Figure_Width, Figure_Height]);
```

---

### Alternatively: Using a Set of For-Loops

```
%Image size properties%
Image_Height = 50;
Image_Width = 50;
Number_Of_Colour_Channels = 3;
Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width,Number_Of_Colour_Channels);

Red_Channel = 1;
Green_Channel = 2;
Blue_Channel = 3;

for Layer = 1: +1: 3
for Column = 0: +3: Image_Width

Index = Layer + Column;
Image(:,Index,Layer) = 255;
    
end
end

%Figure settings%
X_Position = 0;
Y_Position = 0;
Figure_Height = 300;
Figure_Width = 300;

imshow(Image,'InitialMagnification','fit');
set(gcf, 'Position',  [X_Position, Y_Position, Figure_Width, Figure_Height]);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: How would do this using loop

Comment: Similarly, you can through pixel by pixel using a for-loop.

Comment: I'll add how to do that in my answer. Any reason for wanting to use a for-loop over this method?